# Youtube API 3.0 seach list with location param is don't work

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

When I'm using Youtube API 3.0 for searching videos by using location parameter. It returns with error code 400.

Want's wrong with my request? Please help me?

**My Request is**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&location=37.42307,-122.08427&locationRadius=10km&key=AIzaSyC_yvsd3RYZsez_RcjBSgVY1VT8SIK_zr0
```

**Output of above request:**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.search",
    "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear in the docs, but in this case you have to set type to 'video'

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&location=37.42307,-122.08427&locationRadius=10km&key=AIzaSyC_yvsd3RYZsez_RcjBSgVY1VT8SIK_zr0
```